# Is there any pitfall return subject.asObservable() right after subject.next?

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

suppose I have the following code

```
Injectable()
export class MyStore {
    store = new BehaviorSubject(true);
    updateStore(value) {
        this.store.next(value);
        return this.store.asObservable();
    }

    selectValue() {
        return this.store.asObservable();
    }
}
```

Is it possible that the observable returned from updateStore does not have the value updated by next()? Is there any pitfall in the above code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible that the observable returned from updateStore does not have the value updated by next()?

No, observable will always have the value which was passed in `next()`. Having said that, whenever a subscription is done on the return value of `updateStore()`, the subscriber will receive the value which was passed in `next()`.

> Is there any pitfall in the above code?

You need not `return this.store.asObservable()` every time you do "next". A consumer (i.e. who subscribes) need to just subscribe to MyStore.store as "store" is itself an observable.

```
updateStore(value) {
    this.store.next(value);        
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible that the observable returned from updateStore does not have the value updated by next()?

It's impossible. BehaviorSubject is synchronous so the value is set before the call of `next()` returns.

https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/BehaviorSubject.ts#L42

```
  next(value: T): void {
    super.next(this._value = value);
  }
```

> Is there any pitfall in the above code?

Returning an observable from `updateStore()` is pointless. The caller of the function already knows the store's value. There is no delay in setting the value so there is no need for the caller to await a result.

Everything else looks fine.